# Javascript not running in WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm trying to run JS code in WordPress, using a plugin; but can't make it work.

Here on this Codepen page, you can see the element I'm trying to integrate on my site (i.e. a drag and drop feature)

```
http://codepen.io/galaxija737/pen/pHvEi
```

And here, this is working properly.

But then, I can't figure out how to integrate the JS code properly into WordPress; whatever plugin i'm using. And idem into JSFiddle, impossible to run properly the script, as you can see... 
https://jsfiddle.net/szan6shz/)

For instance using "TC-custom-javascript" plugin; when I add the JS code, nothing is running (i.e the drag-drop feature is not working; like on the Fiddle) :

I'm really new at Javascript as you can see. If anyone can give me a hand on this. (I guess i miss something is the way JS needs to be written/integrated)

Thanks a lot!

Greg

Comment: The script isn't working on jsfiddle because jQuery isn't being loaded into it.

Comment: Thanks Miguel, Indeed i noticed that, also I passed all $ in jQuery with success. Thanks https://jsfiddle.net/szan6shz/4/    Would you know how to keep the order (save it) ? I have the "toArray" function but it does not seem to work properly

Answer (score 0):

WordPress runs jQuery in safe mode. This means that you need to call it with `jQuery` instead of `$`. You can call your initial onload function with `jQuery` and pass `$` into the function to define its use throughout the function.

See this example:

```
jQuery(function($){

    $('.theclass').fadeIn('slow');

});
```